# Order of keys in document in mongo query, matter or no?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to find a mongo document based on a value that is a document. Specifically I want to find a document whose `'fb_creative_id'` is equal to `{'ios': 'bob', 'android': 'ann'}`. It seems, based on this console output below, that the order of the key/values matters. Is this correct?

```
> db.coll.findOne({'fb_creative_id': {'android': 'ann', 'ios': 'bob'}})
null
> db.coll.findOne({'fb_creative_id': {'ios': 'bob', 'android': 'ann'}})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5489c7885464bbcc5b6468c3"),
    "fb_creative_id" : {
        "ios" : "bob",
        "android" : "ann"
    }
}
```

Comment: It matters in all cases, sub-document and otherwise http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are quering is subdocument, the field order matter as mentioned in the  [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#embedded-documents)

> When the field holds an embedded document, a query can either specify an exact match on the embedded document or specify a match by individual fields in the embedded document using the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation).

You need to use the [*dot notation*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) here:

```js
db.coll.findOne(
    {
        'fb_creative_id.ios': 'bob', 
        'fb_creative_id.android': 'ann'
    }
)
```